# What is error in my code to send JSON to mysql?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, simplexml

My php function fetches tweets from twitter & return them as json encoded string. A JS script catches that data & POST it to a php script using ajax. The receiving php script decodes json and insert it into table. But there is no data into mysql. Error console shows no error. Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<?php

    function searchResults($q) {

      $host = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=" . urlencode( $q ) . "&rpp=100";
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    //Raw xml
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
      return json_encode($xml);
;
      }            //--------------- end of function

?>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
      var msg_top = new Array();
      msg_top = "<"+"?php echo searchResults('windows');"+"?"+">";
      var url = "msg2_mysql.php"
    var request = null;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
             {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
               request=new XMLHttpRequest();
             }
          else
             {// code for IE6, IE5
               request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
    request.open("POST", url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
             if (request.readyState == 4) {
                     if (request.status == 200) {
                         alert('POST');
                     } else {
                          alert(request.status); //
                     }
                    }
                   }
      request.send("msg_top=" + encodeURIComponent(msg_top).replace(/%20/g, '+'));
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is script I am using to insert data into table

```
<?php  
      $username = "******";  
      $password = "********";  
      $hostname = "localhost";  
      $dbh = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect   
      to MySQL");  
      $selected = mysql_select_db("spec",$dbh) or die("Could not select first_test");
      if($_POST['msg_top']!="")
      {
          $json = $_POST['msg_top'];
          $msg = strtoupper(json_decode($json));
          $query = "INSERT INTO msg2 (id,msg,msg_id,depth) VALUES ('','$msg','ID','3')";
          mysql_query($query);
          if(!mysql_query($query, $dbh))
          {die('error:' .mysql_error());} echo'success';
        }
     else echo('no value!');
   ?>
```

Comment: msg_top[] = "<"+"?php echo searchResults('windows');"+"?"+">"; // Whatever you are doing with this line is VERY dangerous. VERY VERY dangerous... Like... Take over your server and steal your life dangerous. -- To clearify, if you are running that on your server later, someone could use firebug to run ANY code on your server.

Comment: What IS going on with that msg_top? You are eval-ing this on your server in PHP after receiving it from JS? But why would you be sending the PHP tag? Just send the parameters and add it to your code on the server. Not sure that I understand what is going on there.

Comment: @Alex, sorry I did not understood ur both 1st two questions. What do you mean by sending php tag? I want to pass results from php to js. &  js implement ajax that insert those results to mysql when page loads.

Comment: Your code has `<"+"?php echo searchResults('windows');"+"?"+">";`. What does this do? DampeS8N and I both feel that this appears to be indicative of a serious security hazard. Why are you sending PHP code to yourself?

Comment: I found this method from search to get a php variable in JS. In These php tags, I run php search function that returns tweets in json format that is passed to js variable.

Answer (score 0):

These lines are wrong:

```
 var msg_top = new array(); // Here error 
 msg_top[] = "<"+"?php echo searchResults('windows');"+"?"+">";
```

First, it's "Array", not "array".  Really all you need is:

```
 var msg_top = whatever;
```

The problem is going to be how to encode the array from the php domain into a Javascript array constant. I suspect that using a JSON encoder would be the simplest thing to do.

*edit* — I'll repeat the caveat that I don't know php, but your code *might* look like this:

```
<?php 
  echo "var msg_top = ", json_encode(searchResults('windows')), ";"
?>
```

Comment: Gonna say this here too. Passing PHP to be run back to the server from a JS variable is an OPEN DOOR for attackers to run any-old-code on your server. Anything at all. Like erasing the hard-drive or writing over the passwords file to give them direct access, to a full script that installs a hacker kit on your server turning it into a proxy or adding it to a botnet.

Comment: Well, it's not clear where the value is coming from; it looks like it's being pulled from *another* server.

Comment: @Pointy, I have edited & added detail to my question. The data to be saved is actually tweets that php function fetches from twitter. I need to insert all tweets that are returned when page loads into database. For that, I am trying to use ajax.

Comment: @DampseS8N, whats the alternative way to do this. I added the detail, now you could see what I have to do oversll.

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to find a JSON encoder for php - it's probably a standard library facility. Just convert the array to JSON and then echo that from php.

Comment: I could do that as I have had already implemented JSON encoder for sending data that I fetched from table to form. But here as I told I need to pass it to script to implement ajax for sending data to mysql. Can u kindly explain a bit.

Comment: Instead of just echoing out the raw array, echo out the value as converted to JSON. The JSON notation is a subset of Javascript syntax, so it'll end up looking like an ordinary Javascript variable declaration & initialization.

Comment: I edited code and also added php script that I am using to receive and insert data into mysql but it is not inserting any result.